# 'Option values are not specified' when saving configurable

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, model, repository

I have a product import routine which calls `$this->productRepository->save($product);` but it's failing with the following error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException]
Option values are not specified.

Exception trace:
() at /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/OptionRepository.php:271
...
```

I have checked the `eav_attribute_option_value` table and the attribute options all have values. What am I missing?

--UPDATE--

So after further digging, and comparing SQL dumps before/after saving through the admin area, it appears Magento replaces (deletes then inserts) the configurable option settings in the following tables:

```
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
catalog_product_super_link
```

Every time a configurable product is saved... Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Is your import trying to add new options to a product attribute? The error is saying there are options but not values for those new options.

Comment: No, it's inserting a new Configurable with several Simple products attached.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on 2.1.2, if I am setting the values at a store level on a new product, the options dont appear in global, even though the attribute itself is global, not sure why its happening though.

Comment: hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your configurable attribute isn't in product attribute set.
Dont' forget to refresh yor cache after you add it to set.